# Is there a gcc pragma that can ignore a function?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I want a command that will completely ignore a function. Somebody once showed me the command, but I can't find it in the manual.

```
void a()
{
return;
}
#pragma gcc_disable
void a ()
{
return q09w8uifsdf
}
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  a();
}
```

Comment: Just `#if #endif` the whole function out?

Comment: You could use `#ifdef` - `#endif` around it, or rename it by prepending `__`, the compiler will optimise out unused functions.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: The compiler may or may not remove unused functions, but in either case it will still check that they are well formed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Umm... you mean this?

```
void a()
{
return;
}
#if 0
void a ()
{
return q09w8uifsdf
}
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  a();
}
```

Comment: Off-course I know how to do that, but i'm looking for a gcc pragma or underscore.

Comment: @Mikhail What is it that you want this pragma to do that's different? You can conditionally comment out the function if gcc is the compiler using `#ifndef __GNUC__`.

Comment: I remember somebody showed me something and I am sad I forgot. This is not a practical question, this more of a matter of erudition.

Comment: @Niholas Wilson. So I awarded you the answer not because you are right, but because I want to have a high percentage. You answer ignored my question :-)

Comment: @Mikhail Sorry! I did subsequently go and google for you, and read every page of the gcc manual, for every arch, listing the pragmas for that platform. I still couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

For one liners just comment it out

```
#define MAYBE /##/

MAYBE int a (){ return 0;}
```

to keep it

```
#define MAYBE

MAYBE int a (){ return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have any `pragma` directives for ignoring a function from executing.. you can just ignore them using `conditional preprocessor` directives..

`#if` and `#ifdef` can be used to ignore a function..

`#ifdef` checks whether a `MACRO` is defined or not.. and `#if 0` can be used to directly ignore a function from executing..